# What's the difference between combining Rules conditions with AND and just have them follow one after the other?

Tags: rules

Is there a difference between using **AND** in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Conditions and simply adding Rules Conditions one after the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preface: I'm assuming this question is about D7 ...

#### Correction to the prior answer

I'm sorry, but the prior answer is only partially *correct* (which is the same as saying partially *wrong*, [n'est-çe pas](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/n%27est-ce_pas#French)). Please allow me to briefly correct that (before anybody believes it):

- The question is about (contains) "***... using AND in rules conditions ...***", while the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module cannot be used in Rules *Conditions* (only in Rules Actions). Actually Rules Actions are the reason-to-exist for this (interesting) module.
- If you want to do something more complex, then you can ALSO use ***Rules Components*** as an alternative. So "*You can only do that with conditional rules*" is not true.

#### To AND and/or to OR?

Moving on now to the actual question, this is my answer to it:

- This question is a typical [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) newbie question. Since it isn't obvious that within the Rules Conditions there are 3 ways to combine conditions:

  - add an explicit "OR", so that ***either condition*** must be true (for the Rules Actions to be executed).
  - add an explicit "AND", so that ***both conditions*** must be true (for the Rules Actions to be executed).
  - do not add an "OR" or an "AND": that's equivalent to an explicit "AND".
- One might ask then ***`So when do I ever really need to add an "AND"?`*** The answer to that is if you need to more complex logic like in this sample:

  Condition 1 **OR** (Condition 2 **AND** Condition 3)

  In plain English: the Rules Actions will be triggered if either (or both) of these conditions are true:

  - Condition 1.
  - Condition 2 **AND** Condition 3.

#### Rules Conditions inside Rules Actions

**But**, the real [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) fun starts when this (typical) question arises: "*I need to add something like a Rules Condition inside the Rules Actions, how can I do that?*" **( * )**.

To resolve this typical question, there are basically 2 approaches (that I am aware of):

- Use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module. For an example using the Conditional Rules module (for which there is not a lot of docu available), refer to my answer to the question "[How to prevent a node being saved when using the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114955/how-to-prevent-a-node-being-saved-when-using-the-rules-module/178623#178623)".
- Rework the relevant part of your Rules Action(s) into performing a Rules Component. Because in a Rules Component, it is possible to also add Rules Conditions.

  Typical scenario: "Use Rules to perform a redirect for users with at least X user points, after some Rules Event Y happened". To get this to work:

  - Create a Rules Component, with number of userpoints as a parameter. Within this Rules Component, add a Rules Condition (there you are!) to check if the parameter is at least X and add a Rules Action to perform the redirect.
  - Create a rule, triggered when Rules Event Y happened. Retrieve the nr of user points for the current user ([How to???](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)). And add a Rules Action to invoke the previous Rules Component.

***Sweet, no?***

**( * )**: There are dozens of samples that are variations of this question, my favorite one is when some Rules Action needs to happen based on the number of [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) the current user has (and you do not like to use PHP as a Rules Condition, like I do). If you don't see why that's a variation of it, then first try to find out what the Rules Condition for that would be ... hint: it's a Rules Action, not a Rules Condition.

Comment: Really extensive and exhaustive answer, thanks a lot! I finally had to combine AND and OR, so I complete understood the using case!

Comment: @PonzioPilato : merci! ... and sorry I could not let the prior answer just go. Thought I'd try to explain this typical question for "once and forever". FYI: when I first started with Rules, I struggled with the same thing over and over (now I know by heart).

Comment: Oooooooooh yes.

Comment: I'm completely agree! Quite often we, as Drupal newbies, need some clear and simple answers to simple questions that are missing of documentation and waste so much our time. Thanks again :)

Comment: Some people understand things with only a few words (or just reading the source code) ... other people prefer a tutorial to get it.

Answer (score 3):

No difference, except if you want to do something more complex like this:

____ AND _____ OR _____ AND _____

<strike>You can only do that with conditional rules. (If I recall correctly)</strike>

Comment: Sorry to say, but part of this answer is not correct (= wrong). Lucky you ... I rarely downvote answers (and for sure not anonymously). Do you mind if I allowed to correct this with an additional answer? ... So that maybe next time you want to recall it you have something to go search for?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens please feel free to do so :)

Comment: merci for the approval (hm, hm) .. but don't blame me afterwards if your answer would get un-accepted hé ...! Stay tuned ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I will be happy to delete it, if I am completely off.

Comment: No no, no need for delete, it's only partially wrong! Hang on (I'm working on it ... go have a coffee if you're in a hurry/too curious). Or go checkout the newest "promo ad"-proposal on meta.drupal.SE

Comment: Curious for your feedback about my correction ... Ps: I told you upfront to not blame me hé ...

Comment: Curious for your feedback about my correction ... (I told you upfront to not blame me hé ...). Nevertheless "merci" for the inspiration I got from it to add my own answer.